# Brezis, Functional Analysis, Thm 5.2, Remark 1

Tags: functional-analysis

On p.134 of Brezis's Functional Analysis, it says the following,

> Suppose $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is a differentiable function and suppose $u \in [0,1]$ is a point where $F$ achieves its minimum on $[0,1]$. Then either $u \in (0,1)$ and $F'(u) = 0$, or $u =0$ and $F'(u)\le 0$ or $u=1$ and $F'(u)=1$. These three cases are summerized by saying that $u \in [0,1]$ and $F'(u)(v-u) \le0$ $\forall v \in [0,1]$.

However, I really don't understand why $u =0$ and $F'(u)\le 0$ or $u=1$ and $F'(u)=1$ and also $F'(u)(v-u) \le0$ $\forall v \in [0,1]$. Are they mistakes or am I not understanding them?

(The following is the screenshot of the statement.)

[image]

Comment: I would guess something like $F'(0) \geq 0$ would be true, not $\leq$.  And similarly on the other end.  But $F'(1)=1$ is certainly too strong to be true.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! :) And shouldn't it that $F'(1)  \le 0$?

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense.  I'm assuming these are just (serious) typos.

Answer (score 2):

If you have transcribed this correctly, it is wrong.  A counterexample is $f(x)=-x^2+2x+2$.  Over $[0,1]$ the min occurs at $x=0$ but the derivative is positive there.

Or, even better, a line of slope $1$ works just as well:  $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've attached the screenshot of the statement to my original post. Since this book is so kind and good, I really tried to wrap my head around it when I first read it.